# Concurrent Stepper motor execution

Tags: pi-pico

Is is possible to move two steppers concurrently (note- not threaded or interleved code but at the exact same time) with the PIO peripheral on the Pi Pico 2040 ?
Follow up question. The Rpi Pico has two processors. Does each processor have a seperate PIO peripheral?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  You just need to write the appropriate code, download the executable to the Pico, and then run it.